# React Native 'undefined is not an object' when trying to .map() over GraphQL data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, graphql

Running into a strange issue here with data from a GraphQL query in a React Native app. I have a query getting me all properties (physical properties/homes) with a couple fields including 2 nested/relational fields from graph.cool. I only have 5 nodes in there so size shouldn't be an issue at all.

When I log `this.props.allProperties` to the console I see

'undefined'

'undefined'

and then my array of Objects.

But when I try to use `this.props.allProperties.map()` to map over each item and render an element I get the 'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.allProperties.map') error.

It's weird because it seems my data is getting to me but maybe not in time for the render? I can't figure it out.

Here's my code...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Content } from 'native-base';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import { Transition } from 'react-navigation-fluid-transitions';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

import navStyles from '../../styles/navStyles';
import FooterTabs from '../../layout/FooterTabs';

class KoviMap extends Component {

render() {
    console.log(this.props.allProperties)
    return (
        <Container style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
                style={styles.map}
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude: 35.2253342,
                    longitude: -80.8392494,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.0421
                }}
            >

                {this.props.allProperties.map(property => (
                    <Marker
                        coordinate={`${property.coordinates.lat},${property.coordinates.long}`}
                        title={property.propertyName}
                    />
                ))}

            </MapView>
        <Content></Content>
            <Transition shared="footerTabs">
                <FooterTabs
                    activeBtn='map'
                    navigation={this.props.navigation}
                />
            </Transition>

        </Container>
    );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
},
map: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    top: 0
}
})

const getMarkers = gql`
    query getMarkers {
    allProperties {
        id
        propertyName
        units
        address {
            street
            city
            state
            zip
        }
        coordinates {
            lat
            long
        }
    }
}
`;

export default graphql(getMarkers, {
    props: ({data}) => ({...data})
})(KoviMap);
```

Comment: In your render function, can you try `{this.props.allProperties ? this.props.allProperties.map(property => ( ... : "" }`? Basically, just have the markers render if/when it comes.

Comment: Cant you add a condition on the top of the render function like `if(!this.props.allProperties) {  return false; }`. so it will only render when data available ?

Comment: Perfect solution, thanks @JordanDaniels! Being new to React and React Native I wasn't sure that the component would re-render when the graphql data came back.